# Opening a link outside salesforce

Tags: visualforce, custom-url

I am having a text field for entering a URL. I am using anchor tag on visualforce page to display that field.

```
<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none" href="{!contactInfo.TURL}">--Click here--</a>
```

When i enter value like "www.google.com" in that field and when i click on that link it renders like "https://c.cs15.visual.force.com/apex/www.google.com".

But when i enter "http://www.google.com" in that field it render correctly.

How can i make it work correctly without enforcing user to enter "http://" preceding the website link.

Answer (score 3):

**Limited Fix for Question Raised**

Yes without the HTTP protocol, the browser will treat it as a relative link to the current page, to implicitly add this you can adjust the expression in your page like this.

```
<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none" href="http://{!contactInfo.TURL}">--Click here--</a>
```

**Alternative Thoughts...**

Note that you are making an assumption here on the protocol applied, e.g. http vs https, i personally think its better to clarify to users this is an actual web URL and needs to be valid or preferablly if you can, use the URL field type in the platform, this will adjust the value for the user as you desire.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That would generate incorrect URLs if the protocol *was* set in contactInfo.TURL, right?

Comment: Yes, i've updated my answer with some alternative advice, that should suite the requirement better.

Comment: Good one. That doesn't enforce entering HTTP, but it will still end up like that.

Comment: I added one last option using a formula field that I think should work. I don't have too much experience with Salesforce though, I'm still learning :-)

Comment: Yeah that could work if the poster is not able to change the field type from Text to URL, +1 from my side! :-)

Comment: I have changed field to URL and now using it like     <apex:outputLink value="{!contactInfo.TURL}">--Click here--</apex:outputLink>   Still facing the same problem !!

Comment: Trying using <apex:outputField>?

Comment: using outputField works but it shows URL on VF page and I want to show --Click here-- instead of url on VF.

Comment: There is no way to customise the behaviour of outputField its whole purpose is to provide the native functionality of the field type. Is resorting to coding something to emulate this behaviour (checking the URL etc) really worth it i wonder? Is it perhaps the case the end user wants to see where the link will take them before clicking? Just some thoughts, if you need to emulate the platform feature, take a look at the other answer that will help you down that path. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Create a getter method on the controller**

Like:

```
public String getCorrectURL()
{ 
    string someURL = '';
    // ... do some logic
    return someURL;
}
```

And then in your visualforce page, call the setter like this

```
<apex:outputText value="{!CorrectURL}" />
```

That should work.

**Alternative answer that's not yet mentioned**

Create a formula field that adds the http:// part if it's missing, and use that formula field in your visualforce markup.

```
IF(
    OR(BEGINS(TURL__c, "http://"), BEGINS (TURL__c, "https://")),
    TURL__c, 
    "http://" + TURL__c
)
```

That way, you can keep the original input and still get correct output.